# How can I ask setup.py to list dependencies?

Tags: python, setuptools, packaging, setup.py

I have a third-party package which has a `setup.py` file that calls `setup()` in the standard way, passing `test_requires`, `install_requires` and `extras_require`. (It does not use a `requirements.txt` file.)

I am running a Windows machine (on Appveyor) and `pip install` is notoriously poor on Windows with some of the packages. I would like to use Conda.

It seems to me, the ideal way to proceed is:

1. Ask setup.py to list the dependencies it needs, without taking any action.
2. Pass that list to conda to install.
3. Call setup.py with the `install` or `test` command, confident that it will check its requirements, and not find anything it needs to install.

I thought `python setup.py --requires` might do the trick, but it is poorly documented and is returning nothing.

If this a reasonable approach? If so, is there a way of asking setup.py to evaluated its dependencies, and list them without installing them.

Comment: What package are you trying to install?

Comment: @CaryShindell: Does it matter? numpy, matplotlib, scipy, etc.

Comment: I thought if they were having trouble with a specific package, someone might know its dependencies. If it is intended to be more of a general question, my apologies.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`python setup.py egg_info` will write a `package_name.egg-info/requires.txt` file which contains the dependencies you want.

Comment: I note the format of optional requirements is not compatible with PIP/Conda.

Comment: This command didn't create a requires.txt on python 3.6, unsure why.

Comment: This is the correct answer, thank you. Works on modern python, uses existing tools and does not require writing extra code, and provides output in correct format.

Answer (score 8):

You can get `distutils` to read `setup.py` and return you the dependencies.  The command `distutils.core.run_setup` allows you to run `setup.py` in a controlled environment:

```
import distutils.core
setup = distutils.core.run_setup("setup.py")
print(setup.install_requires)
```

The Python variable `setup` has a set of properties which allow you to poke `setup.py`

Comment: What do I do if `setup.py` uses `setuptools` instead?

Comment: It shouldn't matter if it uses setuptools. When I used the code above I was running it on a setup.py written using setuptools.

Comment: You're right, there were unrelated errors in my `setup.py` file that only occurred when calling it this way, not when directly calling it on the command line.