# List packages list from setup.py programmatically?

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py

Given

```
setup(
  packages=['foo', 'bar'],
  ...
)
```

Is there a way to get the packages list (for example with `setuptools`) without having to use regex?

Comment: maybe this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/52701117/5014455

Comment: Note to what @juanpa.arrivillaga linked: 1. "distutils is deprecated with removal planned for Python 3.12." (so in next version) 2. Running setup.py can be dangerous as it can contain arbitrary code in global scope. Only run it for trusted packages. (The linked thing actually says it runs setup "in a somewhat controlled environment", rather than statically checks it. So I wouldn't use this method to check dependencies of unknown/suspicious packages - e.g. see https://twitter.com/ESETresearch/status/1654127211287560194)